# Can you create a linked server in SQL Server and then refer to it with an alias

Tags: sql-server

Can you create a linked server in SQL Server 2008 and then refer to it with an alias.

So, I create a linked server to "SalesServer", but I give it the alias "Sales", so I can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.DB1.dbo.DailySales
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes... the linked server name and the target of the linked server are 2 different parameters to [`sp_addlinkedserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx). Avoid using the GUI and it's obvious.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server = 'Sales', 
   @srvproduct = 'SQL Server', 
   @datasrc = 'SalesServer';
```

Note 1 to the table in the link actually mentions this

Edit:, after comment to another answer

[sp_setnetname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190318.aspx) can be used to change the "datasrc" (ie target) of a linked server. Why use the GUI?